# How to make the code includes duplicates of 3

Tags: python

Write pseudocode to count the total number of duplicates.

Input: `T = [1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3]`

Output: 3 duplicates (explanation: 1 appears three times and 3 appears two times; `3 – 1+ 2 – 1 = 3`)

```
def find_same_num(a):
    n = len(a)
    result = set()
    for i in range(0,n-1):
        for j in range(i+1,n):
            if a[i] == a[j]:
                result.add(a[i])
    return result

T = [1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3]
print(find_same_num(T)) = 2
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask an actual question. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
T = [1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3]


def find_same_num(lst):
    # get the unique elements
    uniques = set(lst)
    
    # then the length of the list minus the length of the uniques is the duplicates
    return len(lst) - len(uniques)


print(find_same_num(T))
```

**Output**

```
3
```

**Micro-Benchmarks**

```
import random
lst = [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(10_000)]
%timeit find_same_num(lst)
116 µs ± 2.11 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit find_same_num_loop(lst)
566 µs ± 5.41 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

The `find_same_num_loop` is:

```
def find_same_num_loop(a):
    seen = set()
    result = 0
    for x in a:
        if x in seen:
            result += 1
        else:
            seen.add(x)
    return result
```

As proposed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69886255/4001592).

Answer (score 0):

You are counting unique elements that occur more than once in an inefficient way. You can do some simplifications and achieve the desred result:

```
def find_same_num(a):
    seen = set()
    result = 0
    for x in a:
        if x in seen:
            result += 1
        else:
            seen.add(x)
    return result

find_same_num(T)
# 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an other way of doing what you want:

```
def find_same_num(array: List[int]):
    occurences = {i: array.count(i) for i in set(array)}

    return sum([value - 1 for _, value in occurences.items()])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    T = [1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3]
    print(find_same_num(T))
```